# JavaScript function not working with anchor tag click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why this function is not working when i click on the Rate me button?

```js
function incrementValue(){
    var value = parseInt($("#rateme").value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    $("#rateme").value = value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a onclick="incrementValue()">Rate me</a><input type="text" id="rateme" value="50" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The function call is okay.The problem might me with the logic.
https://jsfiddle.net/w056zv3L/

Comment: Why would you use inline javascript event handling instead of using jQuery?

Comment: @ErikPhilips It start working if i change id to #number. what is the reason?

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, it's `$("#rateme").val()` not `$("#rateme").value`, that's for DOM elements not jQuery objects:

```js
function incrementValue(){
    var value = parseInt($("#rateme").val(), 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    $("#rateme").val(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a onclick="incrementValue()">Rate me</a><input type="text" id="rateme" value="50" /></li>
```

Comment: It start working if i change id to #number. what is the reason?

Comment: @Rohit it's not about the id, you can change to whatever you like as long as you use it correctly, the problem is that you're calling a dom method on a jquery object, which is not correct.

Comment: It works with `$('#number').value = value`?! Idon't think so. Try again.

Comment: @Rohit update your question with the current code that you claim works.